# How to restrict overloaded function applicability so that it only applies to certain types in order to avoid ambiguous call errors

Tags: c++, ambiguous-call, function-templates-overloading

I have a class that I use to apply functions to each element in a vector representing an image.

```
template <typename T, typename E>
class func1_img_expr_t : public img_expr_t<T> {
public:
    std::function<T(typename E::value_type)> f;
    E e;
    int size, w, h, d;

    func1_img_expr_t(std::function<T(typename E::value_type)> f, const E& e)
        : f(f), e(e), size(e.size), w(e.w), h(e.h), d(e.d) {
    }

    T operator[](int i) const {
        return f(e[i]);
    }

    template <typename E2>
    bool similar(const E2& o) const {
        return e.similar(o);
    }
};
```

Each function is then defined like this:

```
    template <typename E>
    auto ceil(const E& e) {
        return func1_img_expr_t<decltype(call(std::declval<typename decltype(to_expr(e))::value_type>())),
                                decltype(to_expr(e))>(
           [](auto e) { return std::ceil(e); }, to_expr(e));
    }
```

My image type is called `img` and is templatized so I can have `img<float>`, `img<double>` etc., so I can have `img<T> foo` and call `std::ceil(foo);` and it will return `std::ceil()` for every element in the image.

My problem is that elsewhere in the code I have lines such as:

```
int Lx = std::ceil((nx-1)/2);
```

(where nx is of type `int`). This results in a compiler error that the call of the overloaded `ceil(int)` is ambiguous. I can see why, because if `typename E` == `int` then the above is a valid candidate, but obviously it's unnecessary.

The usual advice on eliminating this kind of error (see [here]https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/error-call-of-overloaded-functionx-is-ambiguous-ambiguity-in-function-overloading-in-c/ for example is to typecast the variable (I don't think that would work here as `nx` is already an `int`, the issue is that the overloaded call is valid for `int`) or to remove either one of the functions (well I can't remove `std::ceil`, and I can't remove my function otherwise I lose the ability to apply it to `img`s).

Is there a way (maybe using std::enable_if?) of limiting the applicability of my func1_img_expr_t so that it will only work when passed an `img`?

Comment: It looks like you've just discovered why you will do yourself a huge, huge favor if you completely forget that `using namespace std;` exists in C++. But if you insist on using it, then also creating functions with the same name in your namespace as in `std` is guaranteed to end in tears, and frustrations. Although it should be possible to use `std::enable_if` to handle the ambiguity, this is a lot of work all for nothing, and serves only as means of mitigating bad programming practice. The right solution is to get rid of bad programming practices instead of looking for ways to live with them.

Comment: Your overload can't be in the `std` namespace, so `std::ceil((nx-1)/2)` can't consider your overload. It can't be ambiguous.

Comment: So if I make a namespace `img` and put all my function definitions in that, then when applying them to an `img` call them with e.g. `img::ceil()` it should work? Does the definition of `class func1_img_expr_t` need to be in my new private namespace as well, or just the function definitions?

Comment: @AdrianK-B. The call can't be ambiguous as it is. So I am not sure what you are trying to fix. Even if you are using an unqualified call it can only be ambiguous if you are using `using namespace std;` (which should be avoided).

Comment: But as a general rule: Yes, put classes in your own namespace and functions specific to your class next to the class into the same namespace. That way ADL also works correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed my code now. If you want to put your comments into an answer I'll happily accept it.